# Custom Button Render binding in xaml does not work

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hey everyone I have custom button renderer that animates when you tap/press but the binding in Xaml does not work. If I would remove the renderer to the button the Binding is working. here is my code.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xbutton), typeof(ButtonEventRenderer))]
  namespace Sample.Droid.Renderer
  {
   public class ButtonEventRenderer: ButtonRenderer
   {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Android.Widget.Button thiButton = Control;
        thiButton.Touch += (sender, q) =>
        {
            if (q.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                 thiButton.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Cyan);
            }
            else if (q.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                thiButton.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);

            }
        };
    }
   }
  }
```

When I remove the renderer for button the ICommand Binding is working

```
<controls:Xbutton
            Text="SIGN-UP"
            Image="Add.png"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="#40B5FF"
            BorderRadius = "5"
            BorderWidth = "2"
            Command="{Binding MainPageCommnd}">
      </controls:Xbutton>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Why not set the background color at the Xamarin Forms level using their animation methods?

Comment: @deckertron_9000 can you provide some sample... what I did is Pressed Effect actually its not the color background but using Images Victor Images, so when you press the button you have some effect...